# Move flex-item to separate line on mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want a flex element to wrap to a new line on mobile, under an image like this (see image under). But I cant' get it to work. The only solution I can come up with is to have the content two different places in the HTML, and display:none one of the versions with responsive css. But there must be a better solution. Any help is highly appreciated. [image]

My initial thinking was something like this:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}


/* Ignore stuff under, it's just for aesthetics */

body {
  font-family: arial;
}

img {
margin-right: 20px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

h1 {
margin: 0;
padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
  <section>
    <h1>This is a headline</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Feature 1</li>
      <li>Feature 2</li>
      <li>Feature 3</li>
    </ul>
   </section>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider float on mobile to be able to make the list under the image:

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}
@media (max-width:800px) { /*adjust this like you want*/
div.container {
 display:block;
}
div.container img {
  float:left;
}
section {
 display:block;
 padding-top:25px;
}
section ul {
 margin-top:50px;
}
  
}


/* Ignore stuff under, it's just for aesthetics */

body {
  font-family: arial;
}

img {
margin-right: 20px;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

h1 {
margin: 0;
padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
  <section>
    <h1>This is a headline</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Feature 1</li>
      <li>Feature 2</li>
      <li>Feature 3</li>
    </ul>
   </section>
  </div>
```